# Java Set ordering

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set

We all know that [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)(Except their such implementation) `doesn't guarantee` of iteration ordering .So i tried to make sure this with below sample code .

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<String,String> lMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
    lMap.put("A", "A");
    lMap.put("B", "B");
    lMap.put("C", "C");
    lMap.put("D", "D");
    lMap.put("E", "E");
    lMap.put("F", "F");
    lMap.put("G", "G");
    lMap.put("H", "H");
    lMap.put("I", "I");
    lMap.put("J", "J");
    lMap.put("K", "K");
    lMap.put("L", "L");
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){

        Thread.sleep(100);
        Set<Entry<String, String>> entrYset=lMap.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> e:entrYset){
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+" , "+e.getValue());
        }
                  System.out.println("******************************************************");
    }
}
```

I executed above code many times and found that it is printing records in order.

My question is if java claims [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is unordered then why this records are printing in order . If someone can give me reason with example that would be great.

Comment: Why are you printing 10000 times the thing ? If the map isn't modified the order will be always the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order is the same each time because the hash code of string doesn't change and you are inserting the in the same order.  Hashmap is deterministic, so if you create the same hashmap and insert things in the same order, you'll always get a consistent ordering.

Hashmap doesn't give any guarantee that this ordering will remain **consistent**.  If you insert more items the the ordering may completely change as the hash table is rebuilt.

Comment: That means until unless i don't modify hashmap  the oreder will remain same?

Comment: Yes, that's a much better way of putting it!

Answer (score 2):

A re-ordering usually occurs, when you add new elements to the map. If the map gets resized, the order may change.

Answer (score 1):

Its because String hash code

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

with one letter string it will be h = 31*0+numeric value of character
thus all hash codes are 1) low 2) in same order as letters.
therefore it is likely that they will be returned in this order.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrect. If you look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), it says

```
This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; 
In particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time
```

Note that the document says that no specific guarantee regarding maintaining insertions order can be *guaranteed* in a HashMap. This in most cases has to do with when the HashMap internally has be resized.

Try playing with the *initialCapacity* and *loadFactor* by using this constructor for [HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int,%20float%29) to replicate internal resizing. I think you can see the difference. Oh and when I executed your code, my ordering was totally different from what you posted as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) uses a hash function to put values into set. Therefore its order may change according to hash values. So, you add same values to a hash table with same hash function. That is why you see a order in your set. Try to change a value or order of inserting values. It may change the order of result.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing "is not guaranteed" with "is guaranteed not to be".

Of course HashMap can have some internal ordering.

The only thing the documentation claim is that you should not rely on order of items in a HashMap, and if you do (based on the result of experiment similar to yours) - well, you have been warned.